# Changing IEnumerable<object> into DataRow[]

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I need to get a value of a column of a table, which is at the same row of a specified row. I use the IEnumerable to find it. But the result cannot be transferred into 'foreach', l wish to change it into DataRow[], can any1 help me with this? here's my code:

```
//I wish to change it into DataRow[] findPccID
IEnumerable<object> findPccID = DataSet1.Tables["Pcc"].Select("ID=" + ID).Select(a => a["PccID"]);

foreach (DataRow row in findPccID) // 'InvalidCastException was unhandled' occurs here
                    {
                       //codes
                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are selecting a column. It should be.

```
//I wish to change it into DataRow[] findPccID
DataRow[] findPccID = DataSet1.Tables["Pcc"].Select("ID=" + ID);

foreach (DataRow row in findPccID) 
{
    //You can select the PccId here
 }
```

Comment: Sorry, this is not the one l need. It should be:
User enter the ID, then the compiler will take the value of PccID, which lies at the same row of the entered ID. That's why l need it to be DataRow[], which then can be passed into foreach.

Comment: First of all, l enter an ID, then I use lambda to find the `.length` of ID, if the `.length==1`, then the compiler will get the value of PccID which lies at the same row with the entered ID in the Pcc table.

Comment: @hakunabean That is not what your original code is doing at all

Comment: I'm sorry. I just posted a small part of it because actually my code is connected to 4 complicated tables, so I have trouble want to explain it all clearly. The problem now is, if l can change change the `IEnumerable<object> findPccID` into `DataRow[] findPccID`, then l can pass the value into `foreach`, which I think it suppose to work.

Comment: @hakunabean And that's exactly what this answer does.  The DataRow Select method returns a DataRow[].  The LINQ Select method that you use after that takes the DataRow[] and returns an enumerable of each column.  The DataRow[] is now gone.  You just need to remove the second select if you want the whole DataRow